# Как правильно согласовать глагол?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Верунчик(про девочку) СДЕЛАЛ или СДЕЛАЛА?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: ***Верунчик сделала.***

Согласование сказуемого делается в женском роде, что соответствует  полу лица.

А вот склоняется это имя по 2-му склонению, как сущ. м.р.: Верунчика, Верунчику.

Розенталь, §188.

http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

7. **При подлежащем – прозвище лица** сказуемое принимает **форму рода, которая соответствует полу называемого лица**, например: В августе Редька приказал нам собираться на линию (Чехов); Из-за суконной занавески появилась «Великий Могол» с подносом (А.Н. Толстой) (речь идет о горничной Луше).

Answer (score 0):

Согласовывать надо с подразумеваемой девочкой ("сделал**а**"). Это подтверждается множеством *книжных* примеров, легко находимых гуглом по запросу "Верунчик".

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду "Верунчик - девочка", то "сделала". Если же имеется в виду "Верунчик - ребёнок", то "сделал".

Comment: Ребенок здесь ни при чем. Что тут Верунчик наделал - так говорят В ШУТКУ, используя формальное согласование по м. роду. Но то же самое подружки могут сказать и про взрослую девушку: это Верунчик сделал.

Comment: Не согласен. Когда употребляется глагол в м.р., то и значение для Верунчик надо искать м.р. "Что тут Верунчик (ребёнок) наделал", "это Верунчик (автор) сделал".